# Factoring Decision Problem - why not in P?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

Nielsen and Chuang, 10th Anniversary Edition, page 142, refers to the following (classical) computation problem: Given a composite integer m and L <m, does m have a non-trivial
factor less than L?

They say the problem is thought not to be the the polynomial time class P. I do not see this; it seems you could just perform trial divisions from 2 to L-1 and that would be polynomial time.

Comment: It takes $O(2^{n/2})$ steps to perform trial division on an $n$-digit binary number. This is clearly exponential in $n$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about quantum computing or quantum information. Perhaps somewhere like MathSE would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

For factoring, the problem size is the number of bits in its binary representation.

The best known algorithm form integer factoring has computation complexity that is exponential in the problem size.

However, Lance Fortnow wrote [in his blog](https://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2002/09/complexity-class-of-week-factoring.html):

> Factoring does not appear to be hard for any nontrivial complexity class. This means that unlike Satisfiability we don't have any reason to believe that factoring is hard other than the fact that many smart people have failed to solve it.

And [in his blog](https://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2019/04/what-if-history-of-science-factoring.html) also:

> In my poll of P vs NP and other issues, one of the questions was
>
> ```
>                          Is factoring in P?
> ```
>
> One of the most interesting answers was
>
> ```
>                          I don't really see why it shouldn't be. - Peter Shor
> ```

So, as per Peter Shor himself, there is no reason to believe that factoring is not in P.